# Snowflake|Airflow: How to unload data from Snowflake into xls format

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there any way to achieve unloading data from Snowflake to XLS?

We are using Airflow to load data from Snowflake to XLS file or Converting from CSV to XLS

Comment: As far as I know, Snowflake cannot write to XLS (see https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-location.html) but I wouldn't want to write to XLS anyway because Excel can only handle a certain number of records .... it could be 1 million these days, but a Snowflake table can be much larger than that

Comment: Agree with you but some customer needs data in xls , also it never millions in rows

Answer (score 2):

If you are leveraging Airflow, then you could potentially use Snowflake's Python Connector to load data from Snowflake to a Panda dataframe and then use Panda's to_excel() function to write that data out to Excel.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try that out